# Runtime Error while Casting an object

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, casting

I am working on a `Typescript` project and while the code gets compiled well and in all theoretical domain of the concepts the code should be working, it's not working at Runtime.

> I have narrowed down the issue of the problem, which is that `TypeScript` gets converted into `JavaScript` after compilation. Which means there are no defined classes and variable types (duct typing a.k.a interpreted language).

Now where I need help is to get this to work. Below is the class structure:

**The Base Classes**

When I get the response from an API, I cast it into a base class type

```
class BaseCollectionTypeResponseModel<TObject>{

    protected responseData: Array<TObject>;

    protected pagination: PaginationResponseModel;

}
```

The PaginationResponseModel is defined as below:

```
class PaginationResponseModel {
    protected totalItems: number;

    protected totalPages: number;

    protected currentPage: number;

    protected itemCount: number;

}
```

Now I have an `interface` defined that has a function `ConvertViaAdapter()`, like below:

```
interface IConvertable{
    ConvertViaAdapter();
}
```

A sample class that implements the interface is below:

```
class PlatformResponseModel implements IConvertable{

    protected status: number;

    protected name: string;

    protected platformid: string;

    protected tags: string[];

    protected type: string;

    protected version: string;

    protected description: string;

    ConvertViaAdapter(): PlatformModel {
        return Object.assign(new PlatformModel(), this)
    }
}
```

Now I am creating child classes that leverage the base class functionalities to provide application specific functionalities.

**The Child Classes:**

for example the pagination child class looks like below:
    class PaginationModel extends APIResponses.PaginationResponseModel{

```
    get TotalItems(): number{
        return this.totalItems
    }

    get TotalPages(): number{
        return this.totalPages
    }

    get CurrentPage(): number{
        return this.currentPage
    }

    get ItemCount(): number{
        return this.itemCount
    }
}
```

Now this is where things get tricky:

I have extended the `PlatformResponseModel` like below:

```
class PlatformFunctionalModel extends PlatformResponseModel{

    get Name(): string{
        return this.name
    }

    get IsActive(): boolean{
                if (this.type == 0)
            return True;
                return False;
    }
}
```

I have also extended the BaseCollectionTypeModel, using Generics like below:

```
class CollectionTypeBaseModel<TObject extends YObject, YObject extends IConvertable> extends BaseCollectionTypeResponseModel<YObject>{

    private _responseData: Array<TObject> = []
    get ResponseData(): Array<TObject>{
        if (this._responseData == null || this._responseData.length < 1){
            this.responseData.forEach((data)=>{
                this._responseData.push(data.ConvertViaAdapter());
            });
        }
        return this.responseData;
    }
    set ResponseData(data: Array<TObject>){
        this.responseData = data 
        this._responseData = data 
    }

    get Pagination(): PaginationModel{
        return Object.assign(new PaginationModel(), this.pagination)   
    }
}
```

The problem is on the code line `this.responseData.forEach()` in the above class, I get the error:

> Object type doesn't have the method `ConvertViaAdapter()`.

Now it should all work since, when `TObject` is extending `IConvertable` interface, the list items of type TObject would be having the function defined and implemented otherwise the code wouldn't have compiled. I need help.

**Sample JSON**

```
{"responseData":[{"status":2,"name":"HelloSample","platformid":"A1B2C3","tags":["hello","sample"],"type":"delta","version":"v1.0","description":"Just a sample"}],"pagination":{"totalItems":10,"totalPages":5,"currentPage":1,"itemCount":2}}
```

**Starter code:**

```
var objectData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var myCastedData = Object.assign(new CollectionTypeBaseModel<PlatformFunctionalModel, PlatformResponseModel>(), objectData)
```

Comment: I strongly recommend keeping your data and operations separate. Classes + JSON leads to sadness, and sometimes to insanity and you gain nothing for it. Also you seem confused about duck typing vs interpreted vs compiled and none of that has anything to do with your problem. Your problem is using classes as type annotations and assuming a conversion would automatically be applied. Even in languages with fully reified type systems (e.g. C#) a reflective serialization system is required to handle JSON, XML, and other textual data

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes I am aware of the way `C#` handles serialization and deserialization. I am looking into how can I use `DataContract JSON Serialization and Deserialization` in TypeScipt as well. came across something called [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON). The problem is this code. It works great in C# I've already tested out the flow of the code before putting the question here.

Comment: Don't go down that road. You will regret it or at best, you won't know how miserable you are :p. Such approaches are not suitable for JavaScript or TypeScript. If you consider TypeScript's compilation to plain JavaScript a weakness, you will never use it well. TypeScript is just for tooling and it's great for that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh. Is there a better way you can tell me I can shape the code, I have a service library that makes the API calls and then the response needs to be converted from JSON object to `BaseCollectionTypeResponseModel<PlatformResponseModel>` and then to `CollectionTypeBaseModel<PlatformFunctionalModel, PlatformResponseModel>`

Comment: I suggest you abandon such an approach. Use `interface`s to declare the shape of the API responses and operate on them with external functions or service classes that take plain objects and arrays and return plain objects and arrays. Type these methods with non class types and embrace static duck typing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad This sounds great, I tried to use such an approach and was successful in it. The only issue arose when I was trying to create new objects that have different properties but the values are based from API responses. In the approach you mentioned, I'll have create a class, implement the interface and then process the new values, and 2 more changes in that approach you'll be exactly where I am standing now. Can you please share a sample code that I can look into and see where I went wrong?

Comment: I speak from experience seeing it done both ways. Trying to implement custom (de)serialization in TS leads to brittle, confusing code that is very irritating to maintain

Comment: Maybe if you show me what you tried. One idea that comes to mind is to create an overloaded function declaration like `function get(route: "user", id: number): Promise<User>; function get(route: "address", id: number): Promise<Address>;function get(route: string, id: number) { return fetch(\`api/${route}/${id}\`).then(r => r.json()); }` where `User` and `Address` are `interfaces`. The string literal types overload the method signature so the data comes out in the shape corresponding to the endpoint. Might not be what you need but look at `lib.dom.d.ts` and see how HTML events are declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the example JSON is missing an array around the `responseData`.

Since (as it seems you may have realized) the `responseData` objects are plain JavaScript objects and not `PlatformResponseModel` objects, you'll have to come up with another way to pass a conversion function into `CollectionTypeBaseModel`.  For example, you could pass it as a constructor parameter:

```
class CollectionTypeBaseModel<TObject extends YObject, YObject extends IConvertable> extends BaseCollectionTypeResponseModel<YObject>{
    constructor(private converter: (obj: TObject) => any) { super(); }

    private _responseData: Array<TObject> = []
    get ResponseData(): Array<TObject>{
        if (this._responseData == null || this._responseData.length < 1){
            this.responseData.forEach((data)=>{
                this._responseData.push(this.converter(data));
            });
        }
        return this.responseData;
    }

    // ...
}

objectData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var myCastedData = Object.assign(
    new CollectionTypeBaseModel<PlatformFunctionalModel, PlatformResponseModel>(
        (data) => Object.assign(new PlatformModel(), data)),
    objectData)
```

Comment: You're right about the missing array type in the sample JSON. Please do feel free to edit the question. I am away from my system as of this moment. I'll test out your code and revert back asap. Thank you